# laravel 500 error: This page is not working

Tags: php, laravel

im working on a project with laravel 5.6
on local server everything is working fine and on production as well, but the problem is, two of many URLs that are routing to two files are not working and giving 500 error (this page is not working). i have several file inside a folder, all of them working fine but not that two. permission to the folder and files are the same as other file that working fine. 
will be great if you guys get me out of this error
folder permission:

```
500
```

file permission:

```
644
```

Comment: check laravel.log and find the particular error

Comment: It happens because there will be error in some logic.

Answer (score 1):

Error 500 means that there is something wrong with your code. Since it is a server-side error you can't see it usually on the client-side.
 There are several ways to find out what the error is. You can do simple debugging, check the error logs in `app/storage/logs/laravel.log` ...
I would recommend using the error logs because the nice thing about Laravel is that its errors are very informative.